# FMX rotate bitmap flickers

Tags: delphi, rotation, firemonkey

I want to draw with FMX 2D a TImage, loaded with a sun. This sun should be rotated in a paintbox. Therefor the following procedure is used:

```
var src, dest: TRectF;
     bmp: TBitmap;
     myAngle: single;
begin
     bmp := TBitmap.Create(round(Right-Left), round(Bottom-Top));
     try
          if bmp.Canvas.BeginScene(nil) then
          begin
               src := RectF(PatternIndex * PatternWidth, 0, (PatternIndex + 1) * PatternWidth, PatternHeight);
               dest := RectF(Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
               bmp.Canvas.DrawBitmap(figbig[ImageIndex].Bitmap, src, bmp.BoundsF, 1, false);
               bmp.Rotate(myAngle); // <-- if I deactivate the rotate then the bitmap is shown the right way  
               bmp.Canvas.EndScene;
               myCanvas.DrawBitmap(bmp, bmp.BoundsF, dest, 1, false);
          end;
     finally
          bmp.Free;
     end;
end;
```

For the painting i use application idle. The frame rate is about 1000 per sec. The sun is shown very shortly (perhaps 1-2 seconds), disappears (1-3 seconds) and so on = flickering. When the bmp.rotate is deactivated the sun is shown permanent.
What is wrong?

Comment: Don't use `OnIdle` to drive an animation. Use a `TTimer` with `Interval = 30`. (Also, I don't know FMX, but if this had been VCL it would not have been right to draw outside of the `OnPaint` handler.)

Comment: Without a complete [mre] I can only guess that the slow pace pulsing is the result of wave interference due to too high repaint frequency in sw vs slower pace physical display refresh rate. A typical computer display has a refresh rate around 100 Hz.

Comment: Just a guess: The bmp.Canvas.BeginScene should be paired with a bmp.Canvas.EndScene, which is missing in your code.

Comment: @iamjoosy: I don't think it is particularly missing.

Comment: @Andreas Yup, you are right -should have looked closer.

Comment: It was an accident of mine. I'm new here and I pressed the wrong button. Should be a comment and not an answer. Sorry.

Comment: @PeterKloß: No harm done!

Comment: I'm not sure why you get flickering without a full example. However, I strongly recommend that you apply the rotation by setting the matrix of the canvas you're drawing to. This is much faster using the GPU and won't modify the original bitmap. This may solve your problem. Use bmp.Canvas.SetMatrix(TMatrix.CreateRotation(myAngle); bmp.Canvas.DrawBitmap(figbig[ImageIndex].Bitmap, src, bmp.BoundsF, 1, false); . Also, you don't need the intermediate bitmap. Just draw directly on myCanvas. Finally, use a TTimer for your animation events.

Comment: I tested the solution from XylemFlow. The sun is rotating. Not through the middle. Just through coordinates 0,0 Is it possible to change the coordinates?

Comment: Peter Kloß, you can offset the rotation center by creating a translation by half the width and height of the image. Call this Offset. The full matrix will then be CreateTranslation(-Offset) * CreateRotation(myAngle)*CreateTranslation(Offset).

Comment: I had some difficulties to find the correct syntax. But now it functions very good. Next there is a more transparent Function to create rotated bitmaps optionally with a new size.

Comment: ´´´ Function RotateBitmap(Bitmap: TBitmap; NewWidth, NewHeight: integer; Angle: single): TBitmap;
var  bmp: TBitmap;
     m: TMatrix;
begin
     bmp := TBitmap.Create(NewWidth, NewHeight);
     if bmp.Canvas.BeginScene(nil) then
     begin
          m := TMatrix.CreateTranslation (-NewWidth/2, -NewHeight/2) * TMatrix.CreateRotation (DegToRad (Angle)) * TMatrix.CreateTranslation (NewWidth/2, NewHeight/2);
          bmp.Canvas.SetMatrix(m);
          bmp.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, Bitmap.BoundsF, bmp.BoundsF, 1, false);
´´´´

Comment: bmp.Canvas.EndScene;
          result := bmp;
     end
     else
          result := nil;
end;

Comment: Why is it not possible to format code in comments?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a new size? You can create a change in scale by multiplying by TMatrix.CreateScaling(AScale, AScale).

Comment: If NewWidth and NewHeight differ from original Bitmap then DrawBitmap will resize it.

Comment: Use Bitmap.BoundsF for source and destination. bmp.Canvas.DrawBitmap(Bitmap, Bitmap.BoundsF, Bitmap.BoundsF, 1, false);